# LAMBDA or ARRAYFORMULA with GOOGLEFINANCE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Working on a formula in Google Sheets to return True/False based on searching through an array of data using:

```
=TO_DATE(INDEX(SORT(
   GOOGLEFINANCE(    
     A2,"high",TODAY()-365,
     TODAY()),2,FALSE),2,1))
```

This formula returns the highest date in the previous 365 day period.

Next I need to identify what the largest percentage gain was during that same 365 day time period. It may or may not be during that 52 week high.

Stuck finding a solution so thought I'd ask the community to see if you can help?

Thoughts: Maybe use [LAMBDA function](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273#:%7E:text=Logical-,LAMBDA,-LAMBDA(name%2C%20formula_expression)) and build a custom script like the following to identify. Just not sure how to build this within Sheets as the following example is VBA and just learning Sheets now.

```
Function jumpfound(rar As Range)
  rr = rar.Value
  Jlim = 1.75
  
  For i = 5 To UBound(rr, 1)
    maxv = 0
    minv = (2 ^ 31) - 1
    jumpfound = False
   
    For j = 0 To 4
      If minv > rr(i - j, 1) Then minv = rr(i - j, 1)
      If maxv < rr(i - j, 1) Then maxv = rr(i - j, 1)
      If ((maxv - minv) / minv) > Jlim Then
        jumpfound = True
        Exit For
        End If
      Next j
      
      If jumpfound Then Exit For
      Next i
 
      End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  now, today(), 
  data, googlefinance(A2, "high", edate(now, -12), now), 
  highs, choosecols(data, 2), 
  gains, reduce(tocol(æ, 2), sequence(rows(highs)), lambda(a, i, let( 
    c, index(highs, i), 
    p, index(highs, i - 1), 
    gain, iferror((c - p) / p), 
    vstack(a, gain) 
  ))), 
  filter(hstack(data, to_percent(gains)), gains = max(gains)) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[edate()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974),
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914),
[reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597),
[tocol()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[index()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3098242),
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304),
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461),
[hstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190756)
and
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).